# Upload image with ajax only works png

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, image

I trying to upload a picture (and more text data) using AJAX and it works... but only with png. Uummm... I only tried png and jpg, and jpg doesn´t work.
I am not using a form. This is my javascript code:

```
if(window.FileReader)
{
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(e)
    {
        data["image"] =  e.target.result.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
        $.post('/notifications/simple_message', data, function(result){
           console.log(result);
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(img);
}
```

And on the server side (using node) I have this:

```
if(req.body.image)
{
    var date = new Date();
    var buf = new Buffer(req.body.image, 'base64');
    image = req.session.user.name+'-'+date.getTime()+'.png';
    fs.writeFile('./public/images/users/'+image, buf);
}
```

I am using the png extension for the new file... but I tried using jpg and it didn´t work.
Any idea??

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the cause:

```
data["image"] = e.target.result.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
```

You’re only removing the data URI’s header when it’s a PNG. Make this more generic:

```
data["image"] = e.target.result.replace(/^data:.*?;base64,/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @aaronk6. Finally I make this (and works jeje):

**Client:**

```
var ext = img.type.split('image/')[1];
data["ext"]   = ext;
data["image"] =  e.target.result.replace('data:image/'+ext+';base64,', '');
```

**Server**

```
if(req.body.image)
{
    var date = new Date();
    var buf = new Buffer(req.body.image, 'base64');
    image = req.session.user.name+'-'+date.getTime()+'.'+req.body.ext;
    fs.writeFile('./public/images/user/'+image, buf);
}
```

Really, thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to optimize it further, get rid of the base64 encoding. Just upload the binary data—this will save you some CPU and about 30% bandwidth.